# Generate OAuth 1.0 Nonce, Timestamp and Signature using the RequestURL, ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret in Java or JMeter

Tags: java, oauth, jmeter

How to generate OAuth 1.0 Nonce, Timestamp and Signature using the RequestURL, ConsumerKey and ConsumerSecret in Java or JMeter. I have to send these as parameters in the LTI request.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Running Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article:

- `oauth_consumer_key` - this is something you should have beforehand
- `oauth_timestamp` - Current timestamp (in seconds from 01.01.1970)
- `oauth_nonce` - Any random string (usually current timestamp in milliseconds from 01.01.1970)
- `oauth_signature` - calculated depending on signature type

  - `PLAINTEXT` - URL-encoded Consumer Secret + & + Token Secret
  - `HMAC-SHA1` - base64 of the sha1 of the Signature Base String - the HTTP Method followed by "&", then the URL of the resource (http or https), and then followed by the parameters which are sent to the endpoint and sorted alphabetically - hashed by the Consumer Secret
  - `RSA-SHA1: PKCS#1` - of Signature Base String hashed by Consumer’s private RSA key - and again Base64 and URL-encoded.

More information: https://oauth.net/core/1.0/

So you will need the following JMeter Functions:

- [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) - for the timestamps
- [__urlencode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) - for URL-encoding the signatures
- [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) - for encoding the signatures into Base64
- [__digest()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) - for generating HMAC/RSA digests depending on the signature type

Comment: I followed the same but signature is not matching. Could you please share more on this.